# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'official.vision.image_classification'

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run MBT, scenic repo project(On Ubuntu, WSL). It's throwing an error -

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'official.vision.image_classification'

I have also tried to run the command to install tf-models-official - "pip install tf-models-official" ,it works fine without any error.

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code to replicate the error.